# Find the cardinality of the set of subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Determine the cardinality of the set of subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$.

This question is from a masters exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to solve the particular problem.

Well, I have done a course in Groups and rings but I am unable to solve this particular problem and I don't have any ideas on which result should be used to start this theorem. I understand deinitions and theorems in rings theory.

Please give some guidence.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283199027_Subrings_of_Q

Comment: Subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$ are in bijective correspondence with subsets of the set of primes, see [Maximal subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/412314/152568) (take fractions in lowest terms with denominators not divisible by the primes from the subset). So the cardinality is continuum.

Answer (score 0):

For every subset $S$ of primes the ring generated by $\{\frac 1 s | s \in S\}$ is distinct.

Comment: Can you please give a rigorious argument why ievery such subset must be distinct?

Comment: Sure, it's the fractions $\frac{n}{m}$ where $m$ doesn't have prime factors outside $s$,  the verification is straightforward.